# How to tell a battery is LiPo or Li Ion (based on apperance)?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, lipo

I have this battery and I don't know it is lipo or li-ion:
[image]

Is there any way to tell a battery is lipo or li-ion based only on apperance?

Comment: I guess, LiPo is delivered in sheets like shape, while Li ion are encapsulated in cylindrical shapes. You have a marking 7.4V which is 2 x 3.7 per cell, means a Li Ion, while Lipo is 4.2V per cell.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I thought LiPo batteries also are 3.7 per cell, it is nominal voltage. 4.2V is the max voltage when it is fully charged. LiPo and Li ion have same nominal voltage ?